# So im trying to connect my app backend to a mongoDB server. But im getting a lot of errors and sometimes my terminal stops working

Tags: mongodb, nodemon

This is my `index.js` file:
[image]

This is my `database.js` file:
[image]

I'm getting an error where it says:

```
error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017" and sometimes the terminal crashes
```

Watched a lot of SO questions but they didn't help.

Comment: Do you have any local server running that is bound to all IPs (including IPv6?). Try using 127.0.0.1 as the server IP (on `database.js`) to connect to the local server instead of 0.0.0.0